# Magento not taking new database details

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

Just moved a magento installation to a local server so I can do some work on it.

Changed my DB details in /app/etc/local.xml

Cleared cache and session by deleting the /var/cache/* and /var/session/*

Magento still throwing an error saying it can't connect to the database using theolduser@localhost.

This is driving me insane. What might I be missing.

Comment: what happens if you delete /app/etc/local.xml at all?

Comment: Homepage fails to load - tries to redirect to /install but isn't able to.

Comment: They are definitely correct, even been opened the file in another editor because I thought mine might not be saving. Temporarily removed the version that's online as well just to make sure it wasn't fetching the local.xml from there.

Comment: Please post the error message and make sure that you really only got one *.xml file in the `/app/etc/` folder (Magento reads _all_ *.xml files it can find and merges them).

Comment: Did you change base_urls to 127.0.0.1 in core_config_data? Do a browser cache clear as well. Is it mysql credential errors or connection errors? You may want to reset the password via phpmyadmin or similar and re-enter in local.xml since it is being read properly.

Comment: Did you setup a new local user with the same name and permissions as the production server?

Comment: you do one think, just go to app/etc/ and delete the locl.xml file form that and run your project in the local host ,than it automatically run the install file and create a new local.xml file in it according to your given connection information

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue once, that eats my plenty of hours.Finally i found my database was migrated not completely.Database tables count was matched in local and demo server.Because of constraints error part of database was not imported.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; // top of your exported sql file

//Your database queries

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;  // bottom of your exported sql file
```

Magento [community wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) has article about migrating Magento server to server

You can check your database connection by core php mysql connection.create connection file as db.php in root directory and add bellow code with your db configuration and execute this file to check connection exists or not.

example :-

> $conn = mysql_connect("Your_Host","User_Name","Password");
>   if(mysql_select_db("Your_DB_name",$conn)) echo "yes"; else echo "no";

This may be help you.